# JRuby with a custom ClassLoader?

Tags: jruby, classloader

I'm trying to use a custom ClassLoader in JRuby so my gem's loaded classes don't conflict with any project that requires my gem.

To that end, I can pretty easily create a new `URLClassLoader` and call `loadClass` to get my class loaded but what I get back is an unwrapped Java `Class` that it doesn't seem I can do much with easily.

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
clazz = java_class_loader.loadClass 'org.foo.bar.Class'
wrapped = JRuby.wrap_class clazz

wrapped.static_method 1, 2, 3 # call a static method
wrapped::CONSTANT             # get a constant
```

Any ideas? I've looked all over the JRuby source for a good endpoint and I've tried many of the methods out of JavaSupport like `get_proxy_class` or likewise to no good effect.  I can get and instance of `JavaClass` from my class but it doesn't seem to do me much good.